# Query DCIM folder

Tags: android, uri

```
 public static ArrayList<String> listOfImages(Context context) {
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    //Stores all the images from the gallery in Cursor
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, orderBy);
    //Total number of images
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    //Create an array to store path to all the images
    ArrayList<String> arrPath = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        //Store the path of the image
        arrPath.add(cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));

    }

    cursor.close();

    return arrPath;
}
```

I just want to query only images from DCIM folder. How can I setup cursor query to do it?
This query will return all images from all folder in Android

Comment: Selection .RELATIVE_PATH.

Comment: @blackapps can you write it clearly, I don't understand